# Compactness in a vector space

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, compactness, normed-spaces

If $E$ is a normed space and $F$ is a subspace of $E$, how to prove that if $F\neq\{0\}$ then $F$ is not compact?

I begin by this let $x\in F$ then $F=\bigcup_{x\in F} B(x,\varepsilon)$

how to say that we can't deduce a finite cover ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In any metric space a compact sub space is closed and bounded. (The reciprocal is not true in general). Take $0\neq x\in F$ and $n\in\Bbb{N}$. One has

$$\|n\cdot x\|=n\cdot\|x\|$$

And the sequence $y_n=n\cdot x\in F$ is not bounded ; therefore $F$ is not bounded henceforth not compact.

Comment: the sequence is in unbounded in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: i don't undertant why it implies that F is not bounded

Comment: Any subspace is not bounded, since for any $x$ in the  subspace, $\alpha x$ where $\alpha$ is a scalar must also be in the subspace. See wiki here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Definition_and_useful_characterization_of_subspace

Comment: Yes because if $F$ bounded means $\exists M\in \Bbb{R}^{+},\, \forall  x\in F\,\|x\|\leq M$. The sequence $y=n\cdot x$ has a norm that blows to infinity...